# trajectory with canvas straight ctx.lineTo (y on angle) and (x to desired length)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using plain vanilla html/javascript canvas (no library). I have a way to calculate angles from two points, My theory is that I take the angle and draw a line on that angle by looping the desired horizontal distance (x) and performing some calculation with the angle so it stays straight (y), I can only find stuff about complex curves and circular lines on google. In each loop do I * the angle by its self? I am not very go at visualizing numbers

```
var point1 = {
    x: 20,
    y: 20
};

var point2 = {
    x: 40,
    y: 40
};

// angle method 1
var radians = Math.atan2(point2.y - point1.y, pv2.x - point1.x);

// angle method2
var degrees = Math.atan2(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Update: after MarkE's answer things are looking upside down but much much better...

the light straight lines are showing the angle of a wave line from two points but the angle is some how flipped... I am working at understanding this

[image]

Looks like I forgot to **sin**...

Comment: can you post a fiddle link

Comment: Not working http://jsfiddle.net/z4VJq/481/

Comment: maybe correct http://jsfiddle.net/z4VJq/482/

Comment: no it is way too steep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use trigonometry to calculate the x,y at a specified length along the line including point1 and point2.

```
var dx=point2.x-point1.x;
var dy=point2.y-point1.y;
var radianAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
var desiredLength=150;

var x=point1.x+desiredLength*Math.cos(radianAngle);
var y=point1.y+desiredLength*Math.sin(radianAngle);
```

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sztC8/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle="red";

    var point1 = {
        x: 20,
        y: 20
    };

    var point2 = {
        x: 40,
        y: 40
    };

    var PI2=Math.PI*2;

    var dx=point2.x-point1.x;
    var dy=point2.y-point1.y;
    var radianAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    var desiredLength=150;

    var x=point1.x+desiredLength*Math.cos(radianAngle);
    var y=point1.y+desiredLength*Math.sin(radianAngle);


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(point1.x,point1.y,5,0,PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.arc(point2.x,point2.y,5,0,PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(point1.x,point1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please see my updated image, what you have suggested is very good, only in my case the angles are reversed/upside down